# How can I get text if I have x,y coordinates using Androidviewclient

Tags: androidviewclient

I have x = 402 and y=201  I need to get text available at that specified coordinates using Androidviewclient can anyone help in solving this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ViewClient.findViewsContainingPoint()](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/src/com/dtmilano/android/viewclient.py#L3781) method does exactly that, given a Point returns the list of Views containing such Point, which could be more than one.

Then, you can get the text or any other View attribute.

[culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/culebra) can create a template script for you and then you can edit it and add what you need.

For your case something like this

```
def testSomething(self):
    if not self.preconditions():
        self.fail('Preconditions failed')

    _s = CulebraTests.sleep
    _v = CulebraTests.verbose

    self.vc.dump(window=-1)
    views = self.vc.findViewsContainingPoint((402,201))
    for v in views:
        print(v)
```

Comment: Here is my Code

b = vc.findViewsContainingPoint(402,201,)
print (b)

Error :-
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mobis\Desktop\keypress.py", line 16, in <module>
    b = vc.findViewsContainingPoint(402,201,)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\com\dtmilano\android\viewclient.py", line 3781, in findViewsContainingPoint
    def findViewsContainingPoint(self, (x, y), _filter=None):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Here is my complete code

import sys
import os
import time


try:
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME'], 'src'))
except:
    pass

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient

device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()
vc = ViewClient(device, serialno)

b = vc.findViewsContainingPoint(402,201)
print (b)